# Clear Local Storage on Log OFF

Tags: javascript, angular

need to clear local Storage over different app on Log off

https://localhost:44390
https://localhost:44123

window.localStorage.clear();

local Storage should be clear

Comment: `$window.localStorage.clear();`

Comment: Use the `onDestroy` lifecycle hook in your root component.

Comment: i tried this its not working

Comment: @TheHeadRush we have different projects under single solution so each has own root component . here am trying clear from  Interface app to Documents App .

Comment: You want to clear `localStorage` of `localhost:44123` when you log out in `localhost:44390`?

Comment: @JosefKatič :  Yes

Comment: Then you'll need to use `OnDestroy` in each domain's root component. It's not possible to clear another domain's storage, for what should be obvious reasons.

Comment: Localhost:44123 which  is interface app and it has log off button for entire project .    localHost::44390 is documents app where we storing local storage so if user logs off Documents app local storage should be cleared .

Answer (score 0):

you can clear the browser storage of different types like below in your root component.

> you don't need to use `window` keyword here

```
 ngDestroy() {
    localStorage.clear();
    sessionStorage.clear();
 }
```